# Is there a way to grant SELECT on a table but prevent users creating VIEWs from it?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, sql-grant

I have a table that gets regularly and automatically dropped and recreated. I would like users to be able to select from it but not be able to create `VIEW`s that would prevent this automatic dropping from happening, is there a way to do so? We're stuck on PostgreSQL 9.6, if that's relevant.

Comment: You have to REVOKE the CREATE permissions for these users.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know and the documentation for [Postgress 9.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-grant.html) `SELECT` privilege allow to select from tables and objects you have granted access to, but that doesn't include the creation of VIEWS. To create views you need the `CREATE` privilege, so my suggestion is that you revoke the CREATE privilege to the users and grant the SELECT one